# Add parent object to belongs_to child API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, activerecord

I am trying to put the parent object inside a child object within an API.

So i have Posts --> (belongs_to:Category)

```
  def index
    render json: Post.all
  end
```

This is my controller.. I imagine I need to do some sort of join...but do not know of a way to do it without manually iterating across each post entry, and adding the appropriate Category.

Does active record do this for you?

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT posts.*, categories.name FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON posts.category_id = categories.id;`  Theres the sql i want.. i really need to learn active record :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.all.as_json(include: :category)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Post.joins(:category)` should work as well.

The name of the join would be the name of the association defined by `belongs_to`. (So it is `:category` and not `:categories`)

Comment: The above is producing the following query : `SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "posts"."category_id"`  So it isn't displaying the category object items (:name) for instance.